# How can I call oracle store procedure from codeigniter

Tags: php

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure SELECT_ACC_CHART_OF_ACCOUNTS (ALLS out sys_refcursor)
   is
    begin
       open ALLS for select * from USERS;
    end;
```

Codeigniter code:

```
$query = $this->db->query("CALL SELECT_ACC_CHART_OF_ACCOUNTS()");
echo "<pre>";print_r($query->result());die();
```

This is working showing the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: oci_execute(): ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SELECT_ACC_CHART_OF_ACCOUNTS'

Filename: oci8/oci8_driver.php

Line Number: 282

Backtrace:

File: F:\xampp\htdocs\agro_erp\erp\modules\accounts\controllers\chart_of_accounts.php
Line: 328
Function: query

File: F:\xampp\htdocs\agro_erp\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

Comment: It looks like the procedure you define expects an argument, but you're calling it without an argument. This would match with the error message "wrong number or types of arguments".